# Split an array every time a letter appears to form a longer array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have split a string into an array every time a letter appeared, however I now want to split each string in the array into more arrays went another letter appears, adding an array below each split with the letter removed.

Here is my code:

```
private String input = "118u121u23n24"
private int y = 0;
private String[] split_main = new String[100];
private void split_u(){
        String[] split = input.split("u");
        for(int x=0; split.length>x; x++){
            split_main[y] = split[x];
            if(split.length>x+1)
                split_main[y+1] = "+";
            y +=2;
        }
```

This splits my string into an array like this - creates a new array every time "u" appears and adds a plus

```
118
+
121
+
23n24
```

I now want to go through each of these arrays and look for the letter n and put it on a separate line so this will be the new array. However every time I have tried this I have got errors because I don't seem to be able to use the Split method again on the array. If using split is not possible then is there another way to do it?

```
118
+
121
+
23
n
24
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
String[] split = input.split("u|n");
```

`u|n` means that split string with by `u` or `n`, simply split string by two separator

while you want to add different separator in two levels you should write code like this.

```
    String input = "118u121u23n24";
    String[] s2;
    ArrayList<String> main = new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] split = input.split("u");
    for(int x=0; split.length>x; x++){
        s2 = split[x].split("n");

        for(int k=0; k<s2.length; k++){
            main.add(s2[k]);
            if(s2.length>k+1)
                main.add("n");
        }

        if(split.length>x+1)
            main.add("+");
    }
    // print main array to test
    for(int i=0;i<main.size();i++)
        System.out.println(main.get(i));
```

Comment: but then how can I insert a "+" or "n" between them, depending of which letter I removed, as it is in the example output?

Comment: in this case you must iterate on `split` array and split strings on the second later

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you simply split on all the letters at once, using a regex:

```
String[] split = input.split("(+|n)");
```

If you require the intermediate steps, then the only way to do it is to iterate through the first split, building an array of results of splitting on the second letter. If you want to do this for multiple split patterns (not just "+" and "n"), you will need a general purpose procedure. Here's sample code:

```
/**
 * Replaces one element of a list of strings with the results of
 * splitting that element with a given pattern. A copy of the pattern
 * is inserted between the elements of the split.
 * @param list The list of elements to be modified
 * @param pattern The pattern on which to split
 * @param pos The position of the element to split
 * @return The number of additional elements inserted. This is the amount by
 *         which the list grew. If the element was not split, zero is returned.
 */
int splitElements(List<String> list, String pattern, int pos) {
    String[] split = list.get(pos).split(pattern);
    if (split.length > 1) {
        list.set(pos++, split[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < split.length; ++i) {
            list.add(pos++, pattern);
            list.add(pos++, split[i]);
        }
    } // else nothing to do
    return (split.length << 1) - 1;
}
```

Then you would call this with each character with which you want to split:

```
private String input = "118u121u23n24";
private ArrayList<String> split_main = new ArrayList<String>();
split_main.add(input);
splitElements(split_main, "+", 0);
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    i += splitElements(split_main, "n", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Use `List` instead of array to make inserting new items easy.

If you want arrays only, do it in two passes: first, iterate over `input` and count how many more cells you need because of `n`, then create new array of proper size and copy `input` contents to it, splitting along the way.